# Laravel 5.4 Passport -- How to redirect to client dashboard after getting user info from the access token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

In Laravel Passport, after getting the access token from the server, able to access the user information from the client. Now I am stuck with how to redirect it to client dashboard?

Here is my callback function:

```
Route::get('/callback', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

    $response = $http->post('http://localhost.server:8080/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            /* Auth code grant*/
            'client_id' => '<client_id>',
            'client_secret' => '<client_secret>',
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost.client:8000/callback',
            'code' => $request->code,
        ],
    ]);

        $auth_grant = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
        $token_type = $auth_grant['token_type'];
        $access_token = $auth_grant['access_token'];

        $user_auth = $http->request('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/api/user', [
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => $token_type.' '.$access_token,
            ],
        ]);
        $usrAuth = json_decode((string) $user_auth->getBody(), true);
});
```

**Note**:
Before redirecting to Dashboard, want to store the user info in the `Auth` and later wants to verify every other route through the `VarifyUser` middleware. That authenticating the user through `Auth::check`.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['verify_user', 'language']], function(){
// If you want to check loggining user, have to use 'verify_user' middleware
   route::group(['namespace' => 'Index'], function(){
     Route::get('/index', 'IndexController@index');
   });

   route::group(['namespace' => 'Group'], function(){
     // Group page
     Route::get('/group-registration', 'GroupController@index');

     // Register group
     Route::post('/registerGroup', 'GroupController@registerGroup');
  });
}
```

`VerifyUser` middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

// Requirement
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Closure;

class VerifyUser
{
  /**
   * Handle an incoming request.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @param  \Closure  $next
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
      if(!Auth::check()){
        return redirect('/login');
      }

      return $next($request);
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use redirect()->to() in the end

Comment: Thanks. But actually before redirect, I want to store the user information in ``Auth`` and later want to authenticating the user through ``Auth::check``.

Answer (score 0):

Add response redirect at the end of methods

```
Route::get('/callback', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    // callback handle
    ....

    // here, add this to redirect after callback success
    return redirect('dashboard');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But actually before redirect to the dashboard, I want to store the user information in Auth and later want to verify every other route through VerifyUser middleware. That authenticating the user through Auth::check.

Comment: Sure, it's very possible. I've created gist for more detail code
https://gist.github.com/rslhdyt/cfdee2f3645691e8c2ce92927fcfb876

Comment: Thanks for your response. But you are using the Socialite. How to do it in Passport?

Comment: @PS1212 create custom socialite provider for your own provider.
This is the example how to do it
https://github.com/JaffParker/Extending-Laravel-Socialite

https://medium.com/laravel-news/adding-auth-providers-to-laravel-socialite-ca0335929e42

Comment: Thanks. But I think you didn't understand my question. I'm not using any other 3rd party auth plugin like google,fb etc. I'm only using `passport` where I have my own server and a client web app. I have followed [mattstauffer tutorial](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/introducing-laravel-passport/) and able to access the `access_token`. But difficult to progressed next. Which tutorial didn't explained?